# Getting error when two models are trying to render at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Layout and in that Layout I recieve a model of **PeriodIndexModel**.
Then I renders anothers views in the **@RenderBody** who has differents models.
But when thats others views tries to render, I get this error:

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[ConsumoFE.WebPage.Models.ExpenseListModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[ConsumoFE.WebPage.Models.PeriodIndexModel]'.

This happens to me when I clic on a Sidebar button (u can see it in the CodePen bellow), because that button is going to another Controller who renders a View with a different model.

Maybe u can see it better in the CodePen: https://codepen.io/ignacio-sanmartino/pen/poQXmjm?editors=1010

If u read the comments that I left in the codepen, the HomeController/Index has this code:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(PeriodFilter filter)
        {
            var periods = await _periodBusiness.GetPeriods(filter);
            if (periods.Success)
            {
                ... Generate List<PeriodIndexModel> on periodModel variable

                return View(periodModel);
            }
            return View(null);
        }
```

And the ExpensesController/GetExpenses has this one:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetExpenses(PeriodFilter filter)
        {
            ... Generate ExpenseListModel on expensesModel variable

            return View("Index", expensesModel);
        }
```

I read on some pages that I need to make partial views to render on the **@RenderBody** so I can fix this problem.

Is that correct? Which is the way to do it correctly?

I have a Layout and in that Layout I recieve a model of **PeriodIndexModel**.
Then I renders anothers views in the **@RenderBody** who has differents models.
But when thats others views tries to render, I get this error:

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[ConsumoFE.WebPage.Models.ExpenseListModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[ConsumoFE.WebPage.Models.PeriodIndexModel]'.

This happens to me when I clic on a Sidebar button (u can see it in the CodePen bellow), because that button is going to another Controller who renders a View with a different model.

Maybe u can see it better in the CodePen: https://codepen.io/ignacio-sanmartino/pen/poQXmjm?editors=1010

If u read the comments that I left in the codepen, the HomeController/Index has this code:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(PeriodFilter filter)
        {
            var periods = await _periodBusiness.GetPeriods(filter);
            if (periods.Success)
            {
                ... Generate List<PeriodIndexModel> on periodModel variable

                return View(periodModel);
            }
            return View(null);
        }
```

And the ExpensesController/GetExpenses has this one:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetExpenses(PeriodFilter filter)
        {
            ... Generate ExpenseListModel on expensesModel variable

            return View("Index", expensesModel);
        }
```

I read on some pages that I need to make partial views to render on the **@RenderBody** so I can fix this problem.

Is that correct? Which is the way to do it correctly?

Comment: Can you post your Razor code?

Comment: The model passed to the view in your ExpensesController/GetExpenses action does not match the model expected by the layout (PeriodIndexModel). The layout expects a model of type PeriodIndexModel, but your expenses view is being rendered with a different model type (ExpenseListModel). This  mismatch is causing the InvalidOperationException.